# Raw value for enum case must be a literal

Tags: ios, swift

I have this enum:

```
enum GestureDirection:UInt {
    case Up =       1 << 0
    case Down =     1 << 1
    case Left =     1 << 2
    case Right =    1 << 3
}
```

But on every case I get error:

> Raw value for enum case must be a literal

I dont get it.

Swift 1.2, Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: If those cases are mutually exclusive, then why do you want to assign values 1, 2, 4, 8? And if they aren't mutually exclusive, then you should not use an `enum` to represent them.

Comment: @MartinR I want to be able to do direction = .Left | .Right but I just tested and it didnt work x) What should I use isntead of enum?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's because `1 << 0` isn't a literal. You can use a binary literal which is a literal and is allowed there:

```
enum GestureDirection:UInt {
    case Up =       0b000
    case Down =     0b001
    case Left =     0b010
    case Right =    0b100
}
```

Enums only support `raw-value-literal`s which are either `numeric-literal` (numbers) `string-literal­` (strings) or `boolean-literal­` (bool) per the [language grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351).

Instead as a workaround and still give a good indication of what you're doing.

Comment: I see, so enums in Swift doesnt support bitwise operators?

Comment: it doesn't support any operation. It supports only literals. (1 + 5) won't work either

Comment: @Arbitur no, but it's very easy to do since enums are easily convertible to raw values which you can then or and feed back to an enum.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: But you cannot convert the raw value 5 (for Up+Left) back to an enum.

Comment: @MartinR sure you can `GestureDirection(rawValue: (GestureDirection.Up.rawValue | GestureDirection.Left.rawValue)` but of course it has to be a direction that exists - in this case there aren't any values for `UpLeft` and those would have to be added for that usage (if you want it to be an enum type) of course. Update: Nevermind - I think that's what you were saying.

Comment: if @Arbitur needs bitwise operation, he need to use `struct` and `RawOptionSetType` as purposed in my answer.

Comment: I disagree, only if bitwise operations are one of his primary use cases. I often prefer getting away with enums when possible because of all the other nice properties they have.

Comment: @EddieSullivan that's just the language's definition - what do you mean why? If you want to change that by all means post a swift enhancement proposal.

Comment: It just seems a very arbitrary limitation. If I wanted to say "case three = 2 + 1" I think the compiler should understand that.

Comment: @EddieSullivan I'm not sure why you're surprised - lots of things could be made to work but don't, the default for extending the language grammar is strict. In this case, enum values are known in compile time the compiler would have to run the code (1 >> 2) in this case during compile time and that would pose weird limitations (you can use expressions _but_ only some expressions rather than just literals) which would arguably mean more surprising. This _can_ be solved (like C++ constexpr) - but it's a lot of work to maintain such a feature for marginal gain. I agree it would be "nice to have".

Answer (score 21):

(Answer updated for Swift 5 and later. Solutions for older Swift versions can be found in the edit history.)

For attributes which are not mutually exclusive you can use a `struct` and declare conformance to the [`OptionSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset) protocol. The advantage is that you get all bit operations for free.

You just have to define the underlying storage type and the pre-defined values:

```
struct GestureDirection : OptionSet {
    let rawValue : UInt8

    static let top   = Self(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let down  = Self(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let left  = Self(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let right = Self(rawValue: 1 << 3)
}
```

Usage:

```
// Initialize:
var direction : GestureDirection = [ .top, .right ]

// Test:
if direction.contains(.top) {
    // ...
}

// Add an option:
direction.insert(.left)

// Remove an option:
direction.remove(.right)
```

Comment: Will this enable doing `let dir1 = .Right | .Left; let dir2 = .Left; if dir1 == dir2 {//dir2 allowed}` ?

Comment: @Arbitur: What exactly do you mean with "dir2 allowed"? `dir1 == dir2` is true if they are equal. Perhaps you mean `if (dir1 & dir2) != nil ` ?

Comment: yes that must be it. I want dir1 to be the allowed directions and then check if dir2 is an allowed direction

Comment: @Arbitur: `if (dir1 && dir2) == dir2` would test if dir2 contains only directions which are set in dir1. – One could define an operator or method if you need that often.

Comment: @Arbitur: With the new Swift 2 (which comes with Xcode 7 beta), defining and using the options is even easier, see updated answer.

Comment: This is a solid solution and grants you the same convenient syntax as an enum like you mentioned in the edit. +1

Answer (score 10):

Swift 2.2 Version : 
In my case I needed to Convert the String Enum Values to be used in Localisable Strings. So added this method inside my enum.

```
    enum DisplayCellTitle: String {
    case Clear 

    func labelTitle() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Clear:
            return "LBL_CLEAR".localizedWithComment("Clear")
        }
    }
}
```

And then Use it like so :

```
        // Get the localised value of the Cell Label Title
    let lblTitle = DisplayCellTitle.labelTitle(cellTitle)()
```

where cellTitle passed in is just one of these CellTitle Enum Values

Answer (score 5):

You seems to want a bitwise support for your enums, but if you regards a translation of `NS_OPTIONS` Objective-C in Swift, that's not represented by a Swift Enum but a `struct` inherit from `RawOptionSetType`.

If you need example or instructions, you can look at this [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype/)

That's could be done with something like this :

```
struct UIViewAutoresizing : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ value: UInt)
    var value: UInt
    static var None: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
    static var FlexibleLeftMargin: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
    static var FlexibleWidth: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
    static var FlexibleRightMargin: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
    static var FlexibleTopMargin: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
    static var FlexibleHeight: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
    static var FlexibleBottomMargin: UIViewAutoresizing { get }
}
```

Regards,