# Swift Enum implicit member expression with custom type

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to use implicit member expression in my enum. I did one example in which my `enum` inherits from `String` and it works fine but I can not do the same with a custom `RequestButton` type.

I get the following error: `Raw value for enum case must be a literal`

```
struct RequestButton: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var status: RequestStatus
    var color: Color = .blue
}

    enum RequestButtons {
        case Cancel = RequestButton(title: "Cancel", status: .Canceled, color: .red) // Raw value for enum case must be a literal
    }
    
    var buttons = [RequestButton]()
    buttons.append(.Cancel) 

struct RequestButtons {
    static var Cancel = RequestButton(title: "Cancel", status: .Canceled, color: .red)
    static let Accept = RequestButton(title: "Accept", status: .Accepted)
    static let Delivered = RequestButton(title: "Delivered", status: .Delivered)
    static let ContactSupport = RequestButton(title: "Contact Support", status: .SupportContacted, color: .yellow)
    static let Pay = RequestButton(title: "Pay", status: .Paid, color: Color(.magenta))
}
```

Comment: Did you check [Raw value for enum case must be a literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325058/raw-value-for-enum-case-must-be-a-literal), or other [Q&As about the identical error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Raw+value+for+enum+case+must+be+a+literal)?

Comment: The compiler error is shown on the wrong line, it should be on the declaration of `case cancel`. You cannot set objects as raw values for enum cases.

Comment: @MartinR yes and i can not make it work with a struct also.

Comment: In your case a possible solution should be to add `static var Cancel = RequestButton(...)` to `struct RequestButton` and get rid of the `enum`.

Comment: I tried that and I get: `Type 'RequestButton' has no member 'Cancel'`

Comment: Can you add the code with your new attempt?

Comment: i did. check the updated question

Comment: You have to add the static vars to `struct RequestButton`, not to a separate `struct RequestButtons`. Compare (e.g) https://stackoverflow.com/a/30326021/1187415.

Comment: But I need the model also to create the instance of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use anything other than literals as raw values for enums, as the error suggests.

A literal is a fixed value represented in source code (so no method calls are allowed to construct it).
Swift has String literals (which allow String and Character raw values for enums), integer literals (which allow all the UInt/Int (8, 16, 32, 64) types) and floating point literals (Float, Double, ...). Types that can be constructed from a literal conform to the `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` or `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` protocols.

There are also array and dictionary literals but you cannot use them as raw values.

Otherwise, just use a computed property:

```swift
enum RequestButtons {
    case cancel

    var button: RequestButton {
        switch self {
        case .cancel:
            return RequestButton(...)
        }
    }
}
```