# Swift enum with "computed" int value

Tags: swift, enums

I understand it is possible to declare enum's with int values as follows:

```
enum PT:UInt32 {
    case Fast   = 1
    case Normal = 2 
    case Slow   = 3
}
```

However, I want to indicate which "bit" position in a binary value each element belongs to, so for example:

```
enum PT:UInt32 {
    case Fast     = 1 << 10
    case Normal   = 2 << 10
    case Slow     = 3 << 10
}
```

This makes clear that the options fall into a certain binary position in an integer. But the compiler won't allow it of course. Is there a way to work around it?

I know we could represent the above like this:

```
enum PT:UInt32 {
    case Fast     = 1024 // 1 << 10
    case Normal   = 2048 // 2 << 10
    case Slow     = 3072 // 3 << 10
}
```

But this solution is clearly not ideal. It makes the code really hard to read. Especially when we are dealing with larger numbers. You would need to add documentation in the code to explain what these numbers are.

*For those who dont understand why someone would do this, it is done in the case where tens or hundreds of millions of items need to held in memory at the same time. Int values that don't need a whole byte can be collapsed down to parts of a byte.*

Comment: Great question. I don't think there's a nice solution. One workaround is to implement `RawRepresentable`, but then you have to go through the motions of implementing the `init` and `rawValue` functions manually, and you end up having to repeat your constants twice (and hope that you don't get them mixed up!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? – [Raw value for enum case must be a literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30325058/1187415)

Comment: [This is not allowed by the grammar](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_raw-value-assignment).

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I understand that it is not allowable. Thats why I am asking how to do this in swift.

Comment: @MartinR wow thats exactly the question. It didnt come up when I first searched. That means my question here is a duplicate. I need to work out how to mark it as a duplicate.